# Proving a complex inequality

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $z$ and $w$ be complex numbers with $|z|< 1, |w|<1$.

Show that $|1-\overline zw|^2-|z-w|^2=(1-|z|^2)(1-|w|^2)$, and hence prove that $|\frac{z-w}{1-\overline zw}|<1 $

I'm having trouble getting started with the first part. I tried expanding the numbers out with their real/imaginary components but got a giant mess that I couldn't work with. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** $$|1-\overline zw|^2-|z-w|^2 =(1-\overline{z}w)(1-z\overline{w})-(z-w)(\overline{z}-\overline{w}).$$

Comment: Thanks, managed to figure it out with that hint but I'm still having trouble grasping how those two equations you stated are equal, which properties did you use to get that?

Comment: In general $|z|^2 = z\overline{z}$.